# System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient cannot authenticate against a POP3 server, right?

Tags: .net, smtp, pop3, smtpclient

One of our customer seems to have a very old email system, those that ask you to authenticate to the POP3 server before allowing you to send messages through the SMTP server. Regrettably, we have to believe in what our customer tell us for we cannot access their facilities. But as far as I remember, years ago there were mail systems that once you log into the POP3, the STMP server is kept open for a few minutes for the client IP.

Our application sends messages by using System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient which seems to be unable to authenticate to those kinds of servers. Is that correct? If so, what would be the simplest workaround? I was thinking of a minimal POP3 implementation (just the login part of the protocol). Would that work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: didn't see it mentioned in a quick scan of that other SO question, so I'll mention OpenPOP.NET @ http://sourceforge.net/projects/hpop/

Comment: @Joe. Thanks for the tip. Definitely that was the problem.
I'll just implement the USER & PASS POP3 protocol commands by reusing one of the many alternatives proposed in those posts.

Answer (score 0):

Likely answer: "No", and even if the component supported it very early on, it was removed long ago. Why?

I worked on a wide variety of pre-IMAP email systems, but never worked on one of these.

But my recollection was there were people that linked this together, because  POP client users could easily make this work.

It sounds like you have been able to apply a workaround to your existing environment, POP is a very simple protocol, the RFC says (blah...blah).

I hope that after solving the immediate problem, you can migrate them to something more secure.

I don't do mail security anymore, but a couple important points:

POP uses passwords, and if you are in a programmatic environment, it probably wasn't very strong (many password libraries in the POP3 days hashed the first 8 characters even if they accepted longer passwords) and will have to be hardcoded.

The POP connection is almost certainly not encrypted. (There may have been isolated deployments of POP w/ SSL, but it took the industry so long to get IMAP working over SSL, I doubt an encrypted POP environment is cryptographically secure). All of this is the pre-TLS era.

Last of all, opening transient IP-level open SMTP relay, might sound safe, but is still dangerous, especially because the people who really want to mess with you network love this stuff. It means really basic hackers can't use the gateway, but they can.